# Wordpress load back end translate .mo file

Tags: wordpress

How do I load the .mo translate file to the back end of the plugin?

This only for front end:

```
function my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my_plgin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Comment: This is a guess, but you might try adding the action on `init` instead of `plugins_loaded`

Comment: I tried also `init` hook, the same.